# Understanding knapsack solution

Tags: haskell, knapsack-problem

I'm having trouble understanding the following solution to the Knapsack problem, [from Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem/0-1#Haskell).

```
inv = [("map",9,150), ("compass",13,35), ("water",153,200), ("sandwich",50,160),
   ("glucose",15,60), ("tin",68,45), ("banana",27,60), ("apple",39,40),
   ("cheese",23,30), ("beer",52,10), ("cream",11,70), ("camera",32,30),
   ("tshirt",24,15), ("trousers",48,10), ("umbrella",73,40),
   ("waterproof trousers",42,70), ("overclothes",43,75), ("notecase",22,80),
   ("sunglasses",7,20), ("towel",18,12), ("socks",4,50), ("book",30,10)]

knapsack = foldr addItem (repeat (0,[])) where
    addItem (name,w,v) list = left ++ zipWith max right newlist where
        newlist = map (\(val, names)->(val + v, name:names)) list
        (left,right) = splitAt w list

main = print $ (knapsack inv) !! 400
```

From what I understand, the result of the `foldr` will be an infinite list of solutions for each capacity. We then index the list at the desired capacity to find the solution. But why, in `newList`, do we add the value of the new item for every element in the list? Shouldn't we just add it to `right` because it is the list with capacities over the weight of the current object?

Also why do we `zipWith max` on the `right` and `newList` lists when `newList` contains entries for every capacity, including the ones contained in `left`?

I would also like to understand how one would go about analyzing the time complexity of this. I have trouble thinking about complexities of Haskell programs that use lazy evaluation.

Comment: Big-O upper bounds on time complexity with strict evaluation are also valid with lazy evaluation—the lazy version may have a smaller upper bound and a constant factor for laziness overhead.